# Is there latency when landing a blow with the mighty Mjölnir?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I've had this happen to me before, but wrote it off due to a timing issue.  But I think I'm seeing it more often.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24221426/1079354).  It had been closed with someone that has a gold tag in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) pretty quickly.

Now, an answer to the question comes in about **five minutes after** it had been closed.

How can this be?  It feels like it's a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closing with the dupe hammer is always instant.

However, there is a grace period in which the server will still accept an answers 'in mid flight' to still be posted. That grace period is *four hours*. This applies not just to dupe-hammered posts, but to all closures.

The web UI will disable the 'Post Your Answer' button when the browser is signalled that a post is closed, and a reload of the page will no longer show the post box after closure. But the *mobile* web UI does not disable the button (provided you loaded the page before closure), and you could always re-enable the button from a browser console.

Also see [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed) and [Why was an answer allowed on a question that was merged into another one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one)

Comment: I'll just say it, I guess; the grace period should either be eliminated, or drastically reduced.  Regardless of the state of the browser, answers should not be accepted more than five minutes or so after closure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I agree. I'm guessing that the devs thought it kind to someone putting in several hours to compose an answer, but closed is closed.

Comment: Previously, there was no time limit, but the four-hour limit was added later.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: that changed [four years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63380/its-possible-to-answer-a-closed-question-no-matter-how-old), that's ancient in Internet terms.