# I used my dupeclose superpowers -- and yet an answer was added anyway?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Dead simple case.

I just closevoted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317750/oop-interface-php-does-an-interface-do-anything) as a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463/what-is-the-point-of-interfaces-in-php). I have the PHP gold badge, so the question was immediately closed as a result of my vote cast on 21:20:31Z. And yet [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25317794/50079) was added just afterwards, on 21:21:07Z.

How is that possible, and why does it happen? Is it a bug?

Comment: There is a grace period.

Comment: Also see [Is there latency when landing a blow with the mighty Mjölnir?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260555)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. I suggest you keep the editor open on this page for a while, then add an answer after it's dupeclosed for irony. ;-)