# Answering a question after its been marked a duplicate

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719623/1860929) was marked as a duplicate around a minute before I answered, and still longer than that before other users answered (~2-3 minutes), so how come were we allowed to post our answers?

AFAIK, answering duplicates was not possible unless they were reopened, so has there been a change to this recently?

Comment: Also see [Is there latency when landing a blow with the mighty Mjölnir?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260555)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks Martjin, really helpful :)

Comment: Is it ironic that this question was closed as a duplicate? Although it would have been better if an answer had slipped through as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It would have been ironic if someone would have posted an answer after this was marked as duplicate, so I guess no.